# React styled-component not recognising HTML attribute 'autoplay' of video tag

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs, styled-components

I have a styled component that styles a video tag.

```
const Video = styled.video`
  ...
`
```

And I use it like so

```
<Video width='200px' height='200px' autoplay='autoplay' muted loop>
  <source src={img.src} type='video/mp4' />
</Video>
```

But the `autoplay` attribute doesn't work and also doesn't show up when I inspect the element with Devtools. The other attributes like width, height and loop are visible.

However when I use a normal video tag, the autoplay works and it is seen when I inspect the element.

```
<video width='200px' height='200px' autoplay='autoplay' muted loop>
  <source src={img.src} type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Any idea why the styled-component does not recognise the autoplay attribute?

Comment: As of April 2018 Chrome has changed its policy on autoplay: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: This not style components issue. This related to React semantic attributions changes like `htmlFor` instead of `for` attribute. Changing it to `autoPlay` should fix it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try `autoPlay` instead of `autoplay`

```
<Video ... autoPlay />
```

reference:

['autoplay' attribute](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1649)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using NPM then add the react player dependencies

```
npm install react-player --save
```

If you are using yarn add react player dependencies

```
yarn add react-player
```

import the ReactPlayer component in index file

```
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';
```

Now you can set

```
<YourComponent url='https://www.youtube.com/linkhere' playing />
```

Bydefault it is **False**. 
You can set it as **True** in props or inside the condition.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and thanks to the answers above I could solve it.

The video element seemed working with either autoPlay="autoPlay" or autoPlay, however I had to reload the page manually in order to make it work.

```
<Video
    autoplay="autoplay" // not working
    autoPlay="autoPlay" // working
    autoPlay // working
    autoplay // not working
    muted
    loop
  >
    <source src={DroneShot} type="video/mp4" />
  </Video>
```